# Change values in URL in JSON response then display URL

Tags: jquery, json

I am trying to take an image URL from TwitchTV and display it on a simple website using jQuery and HTML. According to the TwitchTV documentation (and the JSON response I am receiving), the image URLs are returned as:

`https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/ttv-boxart/PLAYERUNKNOWN%27S%20BATTLEGROUNDS-{width}x{height}.jpg`

I am looking to replace the values `{width}` and `{height}` in the JSON URL with `285` and `320` respectively, then pass that URL forward (like displayed below):

`https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/ttv-boxart/PLAYERUNKNOWN%27S%20BATTLEGROUNDS-285x320.jpg`

Here is the current code I have, and I'm only able to display the standard value (with {width} and {height}) so the image is not properly displaying:

```
    for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        var imgDiv = $("<div>");
        imgDiv.addClass("col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-4 text-center");
        var image = $("<img>");
        image.attr("src", response.data[i].box_art_url);
        console.log(response.data[i].box_art_url);
        imgDiv.append(image);
        $("#twitch-container").append(imgDiv);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to use String.replace() for each tag:
`image.attr("src", response.data[i].box_art_url.replace('{width}', '285').replace('{height}', '320');`

Comment: Perfect, I knew it was something simple I was missing. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regular expression to match it.

```js
var url = 'https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/ttv-boxart/PLAYERUNKNOWN%27S%20BATTLEGROUNDS-{width}x{height}.jpg'
var altered = url.replace(/\{([^}]+)}/g, function(m, key) {
  return key === "width" ? 285 : 320
})
console.log(altered)
```

In projects I typically have an object for the look up values

```js
var vals = {
  width: 285,
  height: 320,
}
var url = 'https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/ttv-boxart/PLAYERUNKNOWN%27S%20BATTLEGROUNDS-{width}x{height}.jpg'
var altered = url.replace(/\{([^}]+)}/g, function(m, key) {
  return vals[key] || m
})
console.log(altered)
```